# Oracle - SQL Developer: msvcr100.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, windows64

Have installed 11g in Windows 7 (64 bit machine). Since the SQL developer wont work with 64 bit jdk.

Installed the 32 bit jdk1.7.0
and changed the `ORACLE_HOME\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf` file `SetJavaHome` point to 32 bit jdk1.7.0.

Again started the SQL developer, but it throws `msvcr100.dll` missing. Find that the SQL Developer3.x supports at max jdk1.6.X.

Comment: So why not use the current version 4 of SQL Developer, which uses JDK 1.7.0?

Comment: Yes u maybe right but this is an old issue ifaced on the past and am sharing theis specific problem thanks

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555

Comment: I have the sqldeveloper installed in a custom path on my machine as I don't have admin rights. My user account was removed by mistake by the admins and when recreated I saw this issue. I copied the dll file and changed the SetJavaHome in the sqldeveloper.conf file as prescribed here and all works okay now. I don't understand the down votes as this is a valid issue with valid solutions.

Comment: I had this same issue with SQL Developer version 4.1.3 with JDK included. An answer to this question helped me solve my issue.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

These information is specified in `ORACLE_HOME\sqldeveloper\releasenotes` . So install the jdk1.6 and make the `sqldeveloper.conf` SetJavaHome point to this.

other workaround is go to jdk1.7.0 installed path `jdk1.7.0\jre\bin` copy `msvcr100.dll` and paste it into `ORACLE_HOME\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin` and again try start SQL Developer. It will start.

And The file is from

This file was downloaded from: http://www.dll-files.com

If you downloaded it from somewhere else, please let us know: http://www.dll-files.com/contact.php

Installation instructions:

Extract the `.dll` file from `.zip` file. We recommend that you extract the `.dll` to the installation directory of the program that is requesting the `.dll`.

If that doesn't work, you will have to extract the .dll to your system directory. By default, this is:

`C:\Windows\System (Windows 95/98/Me)`

`C:\WINNT\System32 (Windows NT/2000)`

`C:\Windows\System32 (Windows XP, Vista, 7, win 8)`

If you use a 64-bit version of Windows, you should also place the `.dll` in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\`
Make sure to overwrite any existing files (but make a backup copy of the original file for safety).
Reboot your computer.

If the problem still occurs, try the following:

- Open Windows Start menu and select "Run...".
- Type CMD and press Enter (or if you use Windows ME, type COMMAND)).
- Type regsvr32 .dll and press Enter.

If you have any other problems, see our HELP-section at `www.dll-files.com/support/`

Comment: any comments suggestions problem you had are welcome

Comment: @tuxillo has a far simpler answer

Comment: adding msvcr100.dll to `sqldeveloper/bin` worked thanks :)

Answer (score 28):

Even tho the question is answered I would like to point out that downloading random DLLs from untrusted sources should be avoided.

If you are missing MSVCR100.DLL just install the correct redist for your platform.

32Bit: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86) 
http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=8328

64Bit: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64) 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523

Cheers,
Antonio Huete

Comment: hi kindly can i update my answer to include links you have in your answer , ?

Comment: Hey, yeah feel free! Cheers

Comment: I can acknowledge, that Oracle (tested with Release 12.1) on Windows is still needing VC Redist 2010 64 bit (only!) as a prerequisite. It is a simple as that.

Comment: Best, quickest and cleanest solution for me! No reboot needed on `Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1 x64`. Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem but with 4.1.3 and I just want to note that Visual C++ 2019 and 2013 did not work for me but the one in the link you provided (2010) worked. So, I guess it does not only have to do with the platform - the operating system, it also has to do with the version of Visual C++ used to create SQL Developer version that causes the problem. Am I right?

Comment: I solved this by just downloading the latest SQL Developer. I've added an answer below with more details.

Answer (score 9):

I have just downloaded latest `4.1.3` version with jdk included - `Windows 64-bit with JDK 8 included` to my `Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit` and faced the same problem. Could not start `sqldeveloper.exe`, because "**msvcr100.dll is missing from your computer**".

I did not want to install any additional bloatware, so what I did:

- take `msvcr100.dll` from original download SQLDeveloper folder `sqldeveloper\jdk\jre\bin`
- and copy it to Your's oracle installation bin folder, in my case - `C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin`

SQL developer started!

Comment: Thanks! This did it for me with Server 2012 R2 as well.

Comment: Thanks! Works for me too, old Windows 2008 R2

Answer (score 7):

I got this error while running Oracle JDeveloper.

I have copied the `msvcr100.dll` file from `C:\Windows\System32` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\jre\bin`.
It worked for me. Also check the enviromental varibles settings.

Answer (score 3):

1. Edit `(path)\sqldeveloper.sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf` with Notepad++ or some other advanced text editor. Don't use Windows Notepad for this.
2. Locate the `SetJavaHome` variable. Replace **"../../jdk"** with your regular PC Java source. On mine it was **"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73"**.

   The line looks like this when you're done:

   `SetJavaHome C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73`
3. Save and exit.

Answer (score 1):

The JDK needs msvcr100.dll to either be located in the same directory as sqldeveloper.exe OR already be installed on a Windows machine in a location defined in environment path variable. In testing SQL Developer install on various Windows 7 machines where I have other software installed (not a clean machine), the msvcr100.dll is installed on C: \Windows\system32\msvcr100.dll.

you may get it from sqldeveloper\jdk\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll(refer your installation dir)
I was facing the same issue and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to simply upgrade SQL Developer. When work changed over my laptop I copied SQL Developer between machines and I got the above error except for msvcr120.dll. I copied that dll from my old machine but then it needed another and then another. So I downloaded the latest version of SQL developer and the errors went away. It might not solve the issues for everything but I think updating to the latest version should be done before trying any of the other solutions.

Comment: Can you specify the version before and after please

Answer (score 0):

I installed version 15,13 and 12 and it did not work for me, the links for version 10 are expired, when configuring and installing Oracle Forms & Reports, then you have the version that helps me, I attach the link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#visual-studio-2010-vc-100-sp1-no-longer-supported

```
[visual2010][1]
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#visual-studio-2010-vc-100-sp1-no-longer-supported